# How do I auto generate ids in mysql via hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to auto generate PKs via hibernate with the following code.  Its not working, can someone help?

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="increment")
@Column (name="ID")
private int addressId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this:

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")    
@Column (name="ID")
private int addressId;
```